# Is there a way to easily integrate a set of differential equations over a full grid of points?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, differential-equations

The problem is that I would like to be able to integrate the differential equations starting for each point of the grid at once instead of having to loop over the `scipy` integrator for each coordinate. (I'm sure there's an easy way)

As background for the code I'm trying to solve the trajectories of a Couette flux alternating the direction of the velocity each certain period, that is a well known dynamical system that produces chaos. I don't think the rest of the code really matters as the part of the integration with `scipy` and my usage of the `meshgrid` function of `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, writers
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

start_T = 100
L = 1
V = 1
total_run_time = 10*3
grid_points = 10

T_list = np.arange(start_T, 1, -1)
x = np.linspace(0, L, grid_points)
y = np.linspace(0, L, grid_points)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
condition = True
totals = np.zeros((start_T, total_run_time, 2))
alphas = np.zeros(start_T)
i = 0

for T in T_list:
    alphas[i] = L / (V * T)
    solution = np.array([X, Y])
    for steps in range(int(total_run_time/T)):
        t = steps*T
        if condition:
            def eq(t, x):
                return V * np.sin(2 * np.pi * x[1] / L), 0.0
            condition = False
        else:
            def eq(t, x):
                return 0.0, V * np.sin(2 * np.pi * x[1] / L)
            condition = True
        time_steps = np.arange(t, t + T)
        xt = solve_ivp(eq, time_steps, solution)
        solution = np.array([xt.y[0], xt.y[1]])
        totals[i][t: t + T][0] = solution[0]
        totals[i][t: t + T][1] = solution[1]
    i += 1

np.save('alphas.npy', alphas)
np.save('totals.npy', totals)
```

The error given is :

```
ValueError: y0 must be 1-dimensional.
```

And it comes from the 'solve_ivp' function of `scipy` because it doesn't accept the format of the `numpy` function `meshgrid`. I know I could run some loops and get over it but I'm assuming there must be a 'good' way to do it using `numpy` and `scipy`. I accept advice for the rest of the code too.

Comment: What's the relation `x` arg of `eq` and `solution` (the `X,Y` array)?  According to the docs and according to your hopes?

Comment: So you know (from the docs) the `solve_ivp` expects a (n,) shape `y0`, and that your `eq` returns a matching (n,) shape y_prime.  Why then do you insist on using a (2,10,10) shaped `y0`?  What's the purpose of the `x[1]` in the `eq` definition?

Comment: Okay the hope of the matrix was to have a matrix with all the variable that i could save although it may have been easier to just use different ones. The 'totals' is supposed to be a matrix with all the different changes in the period T solved over all the time (total run time) for both variables x and why. But anyway my real problem is that I want to integrate the trajectories of a full grid of points and solve_ivp just seems to be able to integrate one point (particle) at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, in several variants. The question remains if it is advisable.

To implement a generally usable ODE integrator, it needs to be abstracted from the models. Most implementations do that by having the state space a flat-array vector space, some allow a vector space engine to be passed as parameter, so that structured vector spaces can be used. The scipy integrators are not of this type.

So you need to translate the states to flat vectors for the integrator, and back to the structured state for the model.

```
def encode(X,Y): return np.concatenate([X.flatten(),Y.flatten()])

def decode(U): return U.reshape([2,grid_points,grid_points])
```

Then you can implement the ODE function as

```
def eq(t,U):
    X,Y = decode(U)
    Vec = V * np.sin(2 * np.pi * x[1] / L)
    if int(t/T)%2==0:
        return encode(Vec, np.zeros(Vec.shape))
    else:
        return encode(np.zeros(Vec.shape), Vec)
```

with initial value

```
U0 = encode(X,Y)
```

Then this can be directly integrated over the whole time span.

---

Why this might be not such a good idea: Thinking of each grid point and its trajectory separately, each trajectory has its own sequence of adapted time steps for the given error level. In integrating all simultaneously, the adapted step size is the minimum over all trajectories at the given time. Thus while the individual trajectories might have only short intervals with very small step sizes amid long intervals with sparse time steps, these can overlap in the ensemble to result in very small step sizes everywhere.

---

If you go beyond the testing stage, switch to a more compiled solver implementation, `odeint` is a Fortran code with wrappers, so half a solution. JITcode translates to C code and links with the compiled solver behind `odeint`. Leaving python you get sundials, the diffeq module of julia-lang, or boost::odeint.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

I don't think you can "integrate the differential equations starting for each point of the grid at once".

### MWE

Please try to provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce your problem, like you said : "I don't think the rest of the code really matters", and it makes it harder for people to understand your problem.

## Understanding how to talk to the solver

Before answering your question, there are several things that seem to be misunderstood :

- by defining `time_steps = np.arange(t, t + T)` and then calling `solve_ivp(eq, time_steps, solution)` : the second argument of `solve_ivp` is the time span you want the solution for, ie, the "start" and "stop" time as a 2-uple. Here  your `time_steps` is 30-long (for the first loop), so I would probably replace it by `(t, t+T)`. [Look for `t_span` in the doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy-integrate-solve-ivp).
- from what I understand, it seems like you want to control each iteration of the numerical resolution : that's not how `solve_ivp` works. More over, I think you want to switch the function "eq" at each iteration. Since you have to pass the "the right hand side" of the equation, you need to wrap this behavior ****inside**** a function. It would not work (see right after) but in terms of concept something like this:

```py
def RHS(t, x):
    # unwrap your variables, condition is like an additional variable of your problem, 
    # with a very simple differential equation
    x0, x1, condition = x
    # compute new results for x0 and x1
    if condition: 
        x0_out, x1_out = V * np.sin(2 * np.pi * x[1] / L), 0.0
    else:
        x0_out, x1_out = 0.0, V * np.sin(2 * np.pi * x[1] / L)
    # compute new result for condition
    condition_out = not(condition)
    return [x0_out, x1_out, condition_out]
```

This would not work because the evolution of condition doesn't satisfy some mathematical properties of derivation/continuity. So `condition` is like a boolean switch that parametrizes the model, we can use `global` to control the state of this boolean :

```py
condition = True

def RHS_eq(t, y):
    global condition
    x0, x1 = y
    # compute new results for x0 and x1
    if condition: 
        x0_out, x1_out = V * np.sin(2 * np.pi * x1 / L), 0.0
    else:
        x0_out, x1_out = 0.0, V * np.sin(2 * np.pi * x1 / L)
    # update condition
    condition = 0 if condition==1 else 1
    return [x0_out, x1_out]
```

- finaly, and this is the `ValueError` you mentionned in your post : you define `solution = np.array([X, Y])` which actually is initial condition and supposed to be "[y0: array_like, shape (n,)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy-integrate-solve-ivp)" where n is the number of variable of the problem (in the case of `[x0_out, x1_out]` that would be 2)

### A MWE for a single initial condition

All that being said, lets start with a simple MWE for a single starting point (0.5,0.5), so we have a clear view of how to use the solver :

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# initial conditions for x0, x1, and condition
initial = [0.5, 0.5]
condition = True

# time span
t_span = (0, 100)

# constants
V = 1
L = 1


# define the "model", ie the set of equations of t
def RHS_eq(t, y):
    global condition
    x0, x1 = y
    # compute new results for x0 and x1
    if condition: 
        x0_out, x1_out = V * np.sin(2 * np.pi * x1 / L), 0.0
    else:
        x0_out, x1_out = 0.0, V * np.sin(2 * np.pi * x1 / L)
    # update condition
    condition = 0 if condition==1 else 1
    return [x0_out, x1_out]

solution = solve_ivp(RHS_eq,  # Right Hand Side of the equation(s)
          t_span,             # time span, a 2-uple
          initial,            # initial conditions
         )

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(solution.t, 
        solution.y[0],
       label="x0")
ax.plot(solution.t, 
        solution.y[1],
       label="x1")
ax.legend()
```

### Final answer

Now, what we want is to do the exact same thing but for various initial conditions, and from what I understand, we can't : again, quoting the doc
`y0 : array_like, shape (n,) : Initial state.` . The solver's initial condition only allows one starting point vector.

**So to answer the initial question : I don't think you can "integrate the differential equations starting for each point of the grid at once".**